# Docker: Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Tags: docker

In my docker file while building i want to access files on my host machine from localhost server rather than copying them to the docker context folder (i.e the place where Dockerfile is located)

```
FROM busybox
RUN curl -L http://localhost/latest/myfile -o /root/myfile
```

I get errror:

```
$ docker build -t archlinux/test .
... from localhost : Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

So how to do it.

**Solution:** to use `localhost/file`

Use IP of the localhost for that change the

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80 to Listen 80
```

Or

Best solution is use `--network=host`

```
docker build --network=host -t test .
```

Comment: Which kind of server are you running on localhost? Are you sure it is accepting connections on port 80?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: Sorry i am trying to build first. I am not runing a container.

Comment: change 'localhost' to ip of host and check if the server is running on your host.

Comment: my server is running on the host

Comment: Changing the localhost to ip worked. The connection was getting refused because of httpd/conf/httpd.conf settings. (Changing Listen 127.0.0.1:80 to Listen 80 worked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Docker for Linux, You would need to use `--network="host"` as argument when you are running `docker run` or `docker build` command, then your host machine's localhost `127.0.0.1` will be accessible to your docker container.

Comment: I want to build. I am not running

Comment: docker build --network=host should work as well according to documentation :/

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi yes you are not running a container. but `docker build` runs what is called an intermediate container. so in the end you have a container and it is running and it needs to access the host.

Answer (score 1):

This curl request has some deeper sense?

**Dockerfile can be used anywhere**(not only in your machine). For example, I would like to download the Dockerfile and build an image based on this file... I need to serve a resource(myfile) with a www server and run docker build with `--network=host` parameter - a bit annoying.

**I think you should use [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) command for this job.**

Comment: Thats is the best way too.  BUt the url of localhos is not working

Comment: AFAIK the docker intermediate container wont be able to connect directly with the host unless you do as @sadaf2605 mentioned. and it would be better to follow the `COPY` way

Comment: You can add `myfile` next to Dockerfile and add `COPY` command to your Dockerfile like this: `COPY myfile /root/myfile`. Then you can do anything with it, for example you can get a content of this file: `cat /root/myfile`