Can't access Go web app running in docker container
DETAILS:
I'm running Fedora 41 (recently updated from 40 using the official CLI upgrade method)
I installed Docker using this with the setup repository method
SPECIFICS:
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           27.3.1
 API version:       1.47
 Go version:        go1.22.7
 Git commit:        ce12230
 Built:             Fri Sep 20 11:42:52 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          27.3.1
  API version:      1.47 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.22.7
  Git commit:       41ca978
  Built:            Fri Sep 20 11:41:00 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.7.23
  GitCommit:        57f17b0a6295a39009d861b89e3b3b87b005ca27
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.14
  GitCommit:        v1.1.14-0-g2c9f560
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

I can't access my Go web app (I'm running this web app from Github), I've been following this guide and I've even cloned the exact repo to make sure It wasn't me messing up the app. I've been building the app like this:
docker build --tag docker-gs-ping .
and running it like this:
docker run -p 80:8080 docker-gs-ping:latest
when I send a curl request to the port it should be on, I get this output:

curl -v localhost:80
* Host localhost:80 was resolved.
* IPv6: ::1
* IPv4: 127.0.0.1
*   Trying [::1]:80...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/8.9.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Request completely sent off
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* closing connection #0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

NOTE: My Go web app also doesn't seem to receive the request either, as it doesn't log anything indicating it did.
PS: I've tried running the app and specifying the port with 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 and neither have given different results.
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:80:8080 docker-gs-ping:latest
curl -v 0.0.0.0:80
*   Trying 0.0.0.0:80...
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 0.0.0.0
> User-Agent: curl/8.9.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Request completely sent off
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* closing connection #0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer


I cannot reproduce the issue; I can build & start the image, and access http://localhost:80 to get the message Hello, Docker! <3. Is the container running? Are there any (relvant) logs?

looks like this is what you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998680/docker-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-80-connection-refused
try to tun it like this:
docker run --network host -p 80:8080 docker-gs-ping:latest

also please show the output of docker ps -a

@nmishin - These are not the same problems. The linked issue is the container trying to reach out to the host, and the suggested answer is to attach to host network. You should not need to attach to host network here to access a simple web service from the host machine, the port-forwarding should be enough.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]: where is the Go program listening, and how do you start it in the Dockerfile?  You should not need to disable Docker's networking layer with the --network=host option, the docker run -p option you show should be correct, but it also depends some on the program doing the right thing.

@DavidMaze OP provided a MRE. The repo is linked in the post, and all steps OP executed are also present. What IS missing are details like logs, a docker ps -a, ...
